# Как задать переменной boolean (bool) противоположное значение

Tags: c#

Как задать переменной boolean (bool) противоположное значение ?

Я умею менять значение такой конструкцией :

```
if(threadAline)
   {
      threadAline = false;
   }
    else
   {
      threadAline = true;
   }
```

Но считаю её **избыточной**, можно ли её уменьшить ??

[*Вопрос является вольным переводом*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018289/changing-bool-values-to-opposite-of-the-initial-value)

Comment: я понимаю, что в с# это вопрос уровня сеньйора, но метку с++ лучше удалить, пока не поздно.

Comment: Можно :) `threadAline = threadAline ? false : true;` :-)

Comment: ну, @Harry - это же не наш уровень.

Comment: @Harry пишите ответ, приму как верный :3

Comment: О, исходных вопрос из 13-го года, прикольно )

Comment: В оригинале threadAli**v**e.

Comment: ну так это же "вольный перевод"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делай так :

```
threadAline = !threadAline;
```